# Finding scaling sequences of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I've recently been studying i.i.d random variables and I think I'm starting to grasp the concept. I've been set this question but been given very little guidance on how to answer it and am very confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Consider i.i.d. random variables $(X_i)$ drawn from a uniform distribution on $[0, 1].$

In the following find scaling sequences $a_n$, $b_n$ such that $a_n(M_n − b_n)$ converges in distribution to a non-trivial limit function $G$.

(a) $Y_i = X_i,$ and $M_n = \max(Y_1, . . . , Y_n);$

(b) $U_i = \frac{1}{X_i}$, and $M_n = \max(U_1, . . . , U_n)$;

In each case find first of all the probability distribution function $P(M_n ≤ u/a_n + b_n)$ as a function of $u_n = u/a_n + b_n$. Then find suitable scaling sequences $a_n$, $b_n$ so that you get a non-trivial limit $G(u)$ as $n → ∞$.

Comment: [This might help you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should add some details about where you found problems.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the wording of the question. Also I don't really know how to find the probability distribution function in the terms given

Comment: I think that $G(u)$ transforms to one of the types in the fisher theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to set you on your way. First of all, try to determine the distribution of $M_n$. Notice that

$$P(M_n\leq x) = P(X_i\leq x, \forall i)$$

This plus the independence and equality in distribution of the $X_i$ should lead you to the following formula:

$$P(M_n\leq x) = \begin{cases}0 &, \text{for} \; x<0 \; ,\\ x^n &, \text{for} \; 0\leq x<1 \; ,\\  1 &, \text{for} \; 1\leq x \; .\end{cases}$$

Replace $x$ by $\frac{u}{a_n}+b_n$. You'll see that the middle term should be a familiar form, it should remind you of

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{u}{n}\right)^n = e^u \; .$$

**EDIT** For part b) you'll obtain

$$P\left(M_n\leq \frac{u}{a_n}+b_n\right) = \begin{cases}0 &, \text{for} \; \frac{u}{a_n}+b_n\leq 1 \; ,\\ \left(1-\frac{1}{\frac{u}{a_n}+b_n}\right)^n &, \text{for} \;  \frac{u}{a_n}+b_n > 1 \; .\end{cases}$$

Putting $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=n$ this becomes

$$P(M_n\leq n(u+1)) = \begin{cases}0 &, \text{for} \; n(u+1)\leq 1 \; ,\\ (1-\frac{1}{n(u+1)})^n &, \text{for} \;  n(u+1)> 1 \; .\end{cases}$$

The limiting case is then

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}P\left(\frac{M_n}{n}-1\leq u\right) = \begin{cases}0 &, \text{for} \; u \leq -1 \; ,\\ e^{-\frac{1}{u+1}} &, \text{for} \;  u>-1 \; .\end{cases}$$

Comment: So would I be right in saying something like for a) $F_n(t)=P(M_n<t)$ =$P(X_1,...,X_n<t)$ =$P(X<t)^n$. So as $n$ tends to infinity $F_n(\frac{t}{n}+1)$ tends to $e^t$?

Comment: You're on the right track. But it's rather $P(M_n<u/a_n+b_n)$ you have to look at which will give $(b_n+u/a_n)^n$. But selecting your $a_n$ and $b_n$ properly gets you there. And you can adapt a similar reasoning for part (b). Just be careful in working out $P(U<x)$.

Comment: And for b) $F_n(t)=P(M_n<t)$ ==$P(\frac{1}{X_1},...,\frac{1}{X_n}<t)$ =$P(\frac{1}{X}<t)^n$=$P(\frac{1}{t}<X)$=$(1-P(X<\frac{1}{t}))^n$. So as $n$ tends to infinity $F_n(1-\frac{1}{nt})^n$ tends to $e^-t^-1$? I'm unsure about this second one?

Comment: Would you select $a_n=n$ and $b_n=1$ for a)?

Comment: Yep, and $a_n=1/n$, $b_n=n$ for b) .

Comment: Great, that helps a lot, does my answer for b) look ok as well?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. Just work out the details patiently and you can then post an answer to your own question afterwards.

Comment: One more question, when I put my answer for b) you said it looks more or less good, however i've taken $a_n=1/n$ but $b_n=0$ which contradicts what you've said. I've tried working through but keep coming back to $b_n=0$ which would get it in the Frechet form of the Fisher-Tippett theorem, which is what I believe I am looking for?

Comment: I'd take $b_n=n$.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: See my edit of the answer.